# Simple string match

Tags: python, string-matching

I want to do a simple string match, searching from the -front- of the string.  Are there easier ways to do this with maybe a builtin? (`re` seems like overkill)

```
def matchStr(ipadr = '10.20.30.40', matchIP = '10.20.'):
    if ipadr[0:len(matchIP)] == matchIP: return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def matchStr(ipadr = '10.20.30.40', matchIP = '10.20.'):
    return ipadr.startswith(matchIP)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> 'abcde'.startswith('abc')
True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'10.20.30.40'.startswith('10.20.')
>>>True
```